# How to disable Autofill in angular material md-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want do disable browser's (Chrome's) Autofill feature for my md-autocomplete.
I have also read [#2699](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2699) but since I do not have an input tag in my md-autocomplete, I do not know where to apply type="search"

Anybody already achieved this?

```
<div class="autocomplete" flex>
            <md-icon class="icon"  md-svg-icon="user"></md-icon>

            <md-autocomplete
                    md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
                    md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedUserItem"
                    md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchUserTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
                    md-search-text="ctrl.searchUserText"
                    md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedUserItemChange(useritem)"
                    md-items="useritem in ctrl.querySearchUsers(ctrl.searchUserText)"
                    md-item-text="useritem.Name"
                    md-min-length="0"
                    md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template"
                    md-floating-label="Username">
                <md-item-template>
                 <span> {{useritem.Title}} </span>
                 <span> <strong> {{useritem.Name}}</strong>, </span>
               </md-item-template>
            </md-autocomplete>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: still i didn't get your question well. you mean you want a text box from where you can search items or you want to disable Autofill feature?

Comment: I want to disable autofill feature since it doesn't work well in combination with md-autocomplete

Comment: Which version of angular-material you are using? Try using recent one, they've already added it to library so you don't need to handle that explicitly. md-autocomplete directive is made with input element of type search. You can check that just by inspect element on it.

Comment: I have updated angular-material and you are right, it is of type search. However, autofill is still active. Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source for `1.1.4`, autocomplete is definitely set to "off" and type is set to "search":

```
      return '\
        <md-input-container ng-if="floatingLabel">\
          <label>{{floatingLabel}}</label>\
          <input type="search"\
              ' + (tabindex != null ? 'tabindex="' + tabindex + '"' : '') + '\
              id="{{ inputId || \'fl-input-\' + $mdAutocompleteCtrl.id }}"\
              name="{{inputName}}"\
              autocomplete="off"\
              ...
```

If it's still autocompleting, could it be that you have an extension or add-on that is ignoring the setting?

Also, ensure it is not a caching issue. In Chrome, open the dev tools (F12), click the "Network" tab, and check "Disable cache" (which only applies when the dev tools are open), then refresh the page.

If you are bundling/minifying, ensure you have recompiled/reminified and that the page is in fact using the correct script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code in your controller page if you are using angularjs.
By default md-autocomplete will have an attribute called auto complete which set autcomplete=="off". So please override with the below code . But one thing if you have two md-autocomplete in the same template this will not work.

```
$('input').attr("autocomplete","none");
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when we set autocomplete to `'no'` for the input element wrapped inside the `<md-autocomplete>`.

```
  <md-autocomplete
                md-input-type = "search"
                md-input-name="country"
                onmouseover="this.children[0].children[0].children[1].autocomplete='no'"
                >
            </md-autocomplete>
```

Not the elegant one but it does seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

It just worked for me:

```
<md-autocomplete
...
        onfocus="this.querySelector('input').autocomplete='no'"
>
```